# How to Highlight All Rows Based On Non-Empty Columns - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles

I have a DataFrame that consists of a large sum of data. What I'm trying to do is to look through all values in a column called 'Type' and if it's not empty, highlight that entire row.

This is what I have right now for the highlighting

```py
def highlight_row(rows):
    if not rows is None:
        return ['background-color: blue'] * len(rows.values)

df.style.apply(highlight_row, axis=1)
```

I'm trying to get this to highlight it in the data frame `df` that I'm exporting to a CSV file to view in excel.

Comment: You can't export any formatting through CSV. You'll need to save in another format, like excel, if the formatting needs to be in the file.

Comment: yes, it should work

Comment: @creanion It's telling me that the file type is not valid when I go to open it up in excel. Edit: I forgot to change df.to_csv to df.to_excel.... Thanks for the help!